# Left Panel with no borders in the text

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a left panel on google maps, with border on the `li` but this border should not be visible in text. I want the `li` colors to be different from the text. I am creating the menu by adding li on it.

Here is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zzhy/akfe6164/

```
<div id="panel2">
    <div id="label" onclick="toggle_div('panellist');" class = "vertical-text">TEXT</div>   
    <ul id = "panellist">
        <li>ITEM1</li>
        <li>ITEM2</li>
        <li>ITEM3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Like http://jsfiddle.net/akfe6164/2/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply drop your height and width properties on the text box:

http://jsfiddle.net/akfe6164/4/

```
#panel2 #label {
    padding: 7px 5px;
    font-size: 14px;
    background: #E7F2F9;
    text-align: center;
    color: #000;
    border: 0px solid #000;
    top: 0px;
    left: -5px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: You are pushing out the text on the right if you don't use position absolute

Comment: Updated to use positioning. Good catch